# Workflow in folder

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, folder

Is possible to create a workflow in a certain folder in SharePoint Designer 2013? I need to perform some actions on items stored in a folder.

By default, SharePoint is doing actions on lists or libraries items, but if we have a folder in list or library a workflow will not go into it and will not also perform actions on folder's items.

Any ideas, workarounds etc. will be appreciated. I don't need a folder-level workflow certainly, a solution which allows creating a workflow on list/library with the ability to get folder's items in the scope of workflow influence will be also good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the SharePoint Workflow could not be applied to a specific folder.

Meanwhile,you can check and verify if the item is located under a specific folder by checking the **sourceURL** of the current item as the following:

```
If CurrentItem:SourceURL ends with "foldername"
```

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Workflow can be run on *Content Type*, so the solution is:
Create a new content type based on *Folder* Content Type then use new content type instead of Folder and attach Workflow to it.

[image]

[image]